# http.ResponseWriter don't set header content type

Tags: http, svg, go

I wrote task from book The Go Programming Language by Brian W. Kernighan, Alan Donovan. It's task № 3.4
my handler of request look like this:

```
func handler(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    poly(w)
    w.Header().Set("ContentType", "image/svg+xml")
    fmt.Println(w.Header().Get("ContentType"))
}
```

poly(w) - it's function that return svg file in Writer.
Also, i cheked value of ContentType, and it's is "image/svg+xml".
But when i look in develop menu in chrome(F12) i see this:
[network menu in debug](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ejweg.png)

And, ofcourse, i see xml text of svn file, not a picture.

So, i have question: it's my mistake, or it's bug in golang, or it's normal sutiation.

Comment: Per the answer given this is a typographical error question.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You must set the headers before writing the response body. See the [ResponseWriter](https://godoc.org/net/http#ResponseWriter.Write) documentation for more details.

Also, there's a typographical error. The header name is "Content-Type", not "ContentType"

```
func handler(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
  w.Header().Set("Content-Type", "image/svg+xml")
  poly(w)
}
```

Comment: Wow thanks for this! I've been hunting this issue down for over on hour!